# prepared SQL statements in java

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm trying to connect to a database and update a table in it using prepared statements in a java program -- the database is called "database" and in that there is another folder called Views in which the table ("TABLE") that I'm trying to update is. Here is my code:

```
public void updateTable(Map<String, String> mp) throws SQLException {

    String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1500:orcl";
    String USER = "user";
    String PASS = "password";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);

    PreparedStatement updateTableName = null;


    String updateString =
        "update database.Views.TABLE " +
        "set TABLENAME = ? " +
        "where TABLENAME = ?";

    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        updateTableName = con.prepareStatement(updateString);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : mp.entrySet()) 
        {
            updateTableName.setString(1, e.getValue());
            updateTableName.setString(2, e.getKey());
            updateTableName.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        if (con != null) 
        {
            try {
                System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                con.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException excep) {

            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (updateTableName != null) 
        {
            updateTableName.close();
        }
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
}
    con.close();
 }
```

Whenever I run the code it displays "transaction is being rolled back." Any idea what errors I have in the try statement? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: when I change it to print the exception, it reads ORA-00971: missing SET keyword.

Comment: Instead of just catching, printing/logging exception may giv e some clue

Comment: Did you read the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, @Spiff I did change it to the simplest query with just update TABLE1, but I also took out the :

```
String updateString =
    "update database.Views.TABLE " +
    "set TABLENAME = ? " +
    "where TABLENAME = ?";
```

and combined it into one line with the

```
updateTableName = con.prepareStatement(updateString)
```

to make :

```
updateTableName = con.prepareStatement(update TABLE1 set TABLENAME = ? where TABLENAME = ?);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    "update database.Views.TABLE" +
    "set TABLENAME = ?" +
    "where TABLENAME = ?";
```

The value of this string is

```
update database.Views.TABLEset TABLENAME = ?where TABLENAME = ?
```

That is not valid SQL.

Comment: I messed up spacing yeah, but is "database.Views.TABLE" not valid?

Comment: @user22 did you try fixing the spacing?

Comment: @djechlin yeah I fixed that

Answer (score 0):

You should try logging the `SQLException` you catch in the 1st catch block, that would give you a clear indication of what the problem is.

In any case, `TABLE` is a SQL-reserved keyword and you should not be allowed to name a table like that - at least try renaming it to `TABLE1` for lack of a better name.

Comment: The table is a different name in my program I just changed it here so that's not an issue. But when I logged it it says it's "missing SET keyword"

Comment: What does the query look like now? It looks like the spacing issue hasn't been resolved.

Comment: And what does the query look like? "missing SET keyword" says that there is no "SET" in your "UPDATE" query.

Comment: yeah that's what I figured it meant, but my query is the "String updateString" in my code  "update database.Views.TABLE " + "set TABLENAME = ? " + "where TABLENAME = ?";

Comment: I've never used fully-qualified names like this (Database.Views.TABLE1) or seen this "Folder" thing in Oracle... Have you tried just sending the simplest query: update TABLE1 set TABLENAME = ? where TABLENAME = ?